# Get access token in middleware .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to get the access_token in my middleware class after one authentication process in .net core.

I am getting my token in my controllers using this code

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

But when I want to get it on the middleware which is called after the authentication part the method `GetTokenAsync` is not existing for the HttpContext.

My middleware class is this

```
public class Session
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public Session(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var accessToken = // here I want to get my token

            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

I tried different ways and I have been looking for a long time for answers but I still have no solution.

I think that the HttpContext class is different in Middleware and Controllers but I don't know how to solve this in the Middleware.

Someone knows how can I get access to the token in the middleware call or if it is even possible?

My startup callins are theese, maybe it is usefull too.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMiddleware<Session>();
app.UseMvc();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;` to your middleware file.
That's the namespace of the `AuthenticationTokenExtensions` with the `GetTokenAsync` method.

Comment: Hello pinki.. can you help with sample code.. I want to do some operations on ADF under the identity of logged in user to my web app. Thanks

Comment: I have webapp to make changes in ADF (kinda deployment of objects in ADF). I want to authenticate user against ADF. I am able to detect who is accessing web app. I get Azure AD Id like user1@company.com. I want to validate if the same user has access to ADF and generate bearer token to make changes in ADF (using rest api) or using SDK.

Comment: I think you should open a new question for this.

Answer (score 2):

If the `access token`is not in the `HttpContext` and `GetTokenAsync` returns empty, you can also use the HTTP header directly:

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // code dealing with the request
        var result = await context.GetTokenAsync("access_token") ?? context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        await _next(context);
        // code dealing with the response
    }
```

Please also be aware that `GetTokenAsync` will give you the token while `context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]` will give you "bearer sdfosidfds99wn20j293n...". You need to parse the header like this

```
result.Substring(7); // size of bearer + whitespace
```